# Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. Build Output " test ignored "

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

i find this detail in build output
3 of them they have test ignored and the other all seems okay can you help how i fix the one with test ignored

build failed


:app:compileFlutterBuildDebug

:app:preBuild

:app:preDebugBuild

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig

:app:cleanMergeDebugAssets

:app:mergeDebugShaders

test ignored :app:compileDebugShaders

:app:generateDebugAssets

:app:generateDebugResValues

:app:processDebugGoogleServices

:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests

:app:extractDeepLinksDebug

:app:javaPreCompileDebug

test ignored :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata

test ignored :app:processDebugJavaRes

:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

:app:validateSigningDebug

:app:writeDebugAppMetadata

:app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersionsenter
[image]

Comment: `test ignored :app:compileDebugShaders` If you click where it says 'ignored' and share the error code in the right window, we can see the error message and maybe we can solve your problem.

Comment: when i click on it doesn't show anythink and the button from menu to jump to source i can't  click on it